# Why Converting command char double pointer to char is not working in case of command line argument?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, endianness

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "ConvertEndianess.h"

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
void ConvertEndianess(uint8_t* buffAddr, uint8_t length);

void ConvertEndianess(uint8_t *buffAddr, uint8_t length)
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t data;

    for (i = 0U; i < (length / 2U); i++)
    {
        data = buffAddr[i];
        buffAddr[i] = buffAddr[(length - 1U) - i];
        buffAddr[(length - 1U) - i] = data;
    }
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("\nNumber Of Arguments Passed: %d\n",argc); 
        if(argc < 3){
                printf("Too Few Arguments\n");
        }
        else if(argc > 3){
                printf("Too Many Arguments\n");
        }
        else{
                printf("data indianess: %s\n",argv[1]);
                ConvertEndianess((uint8_t *)&argv[1], (uint8_t)(*argv[2]));
                printf("data indianess: %s\n",argv[1]);
        }
}
```

Here is my argument:

> ./a 11223344 4

It is printing correctly before going to conversion API but maybe some casting mistake is done by me and I'm not able to identify it.

Can anyone please correct my mistake with explanation?

Comment: Try `(uint8_t *)&argv[1]` --> `(uint8_t *)argv[1]`.  (drop &) and employ [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257135/2410359)

Comment: On a sidenote: why not use `char` from the start? `uint8_t` etc. should be used if integer processing is used, `char` is fine for characters. Unnecessary casts inhibit the compiler helping you detect errors in your code like the one shown. Reduce casts to an absolute minimum and design your interfaces clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
(uint8_t)(*argv[2])
```

`argv[2]` is a `char *` and according to how your program operates, I assume that is supposed to contain the size of the buffer. Since this is a string (char *), and you want to convert it to a number, you'll need to use sscanf to get this value:

Sample useage:

```
size_t len;
sscanf(str, "%zu", &len);
```

Then pass `len` as the second argument of your conversion function.

The way you are doing it presently passes the ASCII code for the first character of `argv[2]`. So if the user said the size is `"7"` you are actually passing the integer `55` to the conversion function.

As a side note, use `size_t` to represent size, not `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem on your code is that you cast `&argv[...]` with an incompatible type.

`argv[...]` is a `char*` so `&argv[...]` is some `char**`, and you cast it as a `uint8_t*` which is incompatible.

Some remarks:

- You should not type `&` before `argv[...]`:
- You can use `strlen()` instead of passing an argument
- You can use `strtol()` to convert a string into an integer
- **I**ndianness or **E**ndianness?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol */

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

void ConvertEndianess(uint8_t *buffAddr, uint8_t length)
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t data;

    for (i = 0U; i < (length / 2U); i++)
    {
        data = buffAddr[i];
        buffAddr[i] = buffAddr[(length - 1U) - i];
        buffAddr[(length - 1U) - i] = data;
    }
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("\nNumber Of Arguments Passed: %d\n",argc); 
    if(argc == 2){
        /* exemple with strlen */
        printf("data Endianess: %s\n",argv[1]);
        ConvertEndianess(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        printf("data Endianess: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    else if(argc == 3){
        /* exemple with strtol */
        printf("data Endianess: %s\n",argv[1]);
        ConvertEndianess((uint8_t *)argv[1], strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0));
        printf("data Endianess: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }

}
```